# Pandas value_counts(sort=False) with large series doesn't work

Tags: pandas

By default `Series.values_counts` is sorted by the count, in descending order:

```
In [192]: pd.Series([3,0,2,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,2,2,2,2,2,0,0,2]).value_counts()
Out[192]: 
0    10
2     7
1     4
3     1
dtype: int64
```

If I pass `sort=False`, it appears to try and sort by the value key instead:

```
In [193]: pd.Series([3,0,2,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,2,2,2,2,2,0,0,2]).value_counts(sort=False)
Out[193]: 
0    10
1     4
2     7
3     1
dtype: int64
```

However when I increase the length of the series, the sorting reverts to the original order:

```
In [194]: pd.Series([3,0,2,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,2,2,2,2,2,0,0,2]*100).value_counts(sort=False)
Out[194]: 
0    1000
2     700
1     400
3     100
dtype: int64
```

Any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: `value_counts(sort=False)` makes no claims about the sort order of the result. The sorting by key in your first example is an implementation detail, and you shouldn't rely on its sorting behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is correct. You asked `.value_counts()` not to sort the result, so it doesn't. Below I emulate what `sort=True` actually does, which is simply a sort_values. If you don't sort, then you will get the result of the counts which is done by a hash table and consequently is in an arbitrary order.

```
In [39]: pd.Series([3,0,2,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,2,2,2,2,2,0,0,2]).value_counts(sort=False).sort_values(ascending=False)
Out[39]: 
0    10
2     7
1     4
3     1
dtype: int64

In [40]: pd.Series([3,0,2,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,2,2,2,2,2,0,0,2]*100).value_counts(sort=False).sort_values(ascending=False)
Out[40]: 
0    1000
2     700
1     400
3     100
dtype: int64
```

Comment: OK I guess that makes sense. How would you sort `values_counts` by key then? I assumed that this would be an inbuilt functionality since without this it  pretty much makes `value_counts` useless for ploting grouped bar charts which is the only thing i ever want to use it for.

Comment: .sort_index() to sort by the index